# Find the functions $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $n-times$ differentiable such that $f^{(n)}(x)f^n(x)=x$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Find the functions $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $n-times$ differentiable such that $f^{(n)}(x)f^n(x)=x$, where $x>0$ and $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of the function. $I_n=f^{(n)}(x)f^n(x)$ and by integration, $I_n=f^{(n-2)}(x)f^{n-1}(x)-(n-1)I_{n-2}$ and $f^{(n+1)}(x)f^{n}(x)+nf^{(n)}(x)f^{n-1}(x)f'(x)=1$, but I am unsure on how to continue this.

Comment: Why don't you use that $f^{n}(x) = \pm \sqrt{x}$ ?

Comment: @Luis I don't think its helping him. I tried this substitution.

Comment: @SeptimiuCristian  please ignore my previous comment. It seems that the question was edited and now my comment doesn't help at all.